# Convert IEnumerable (to array, list) in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, ienumerable

It seems that in Views, there is limited libraries available (is it true?), see below:
[image: a screenshot showing the available methods for the IEnumerable]

My question is how do I convert an IEnumerable to, say, an array or a list? I normally can use methods like `ToArray()`, `ToList()`, or `Cast<T>()` in a regular C# file, but they all seem to have disappeared when it comes to Views (in ASP.NET MVC).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<%@ import namespace='System.Linq' %>`

You can also add your namespace in the `Web.config`, i.e.:

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace='System.Linq' />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: you probably want double quote?